# Iterate through pandas rows efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, set

I have a list that looks like this:

```
lst = ['a','b','c']
```

and a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id  col1
1   ['a','c']
2   ['b']
3   ['b', 'a']
```

I am looking to create a new column in the dataframe that has the length of the intersection of the lst and the individual lists from col1

```
id  col1         intersect
1   ['a','c']    2
2   ['b']        1
3   ['d', 'a']   1
```

Currently my code looks like this:

```
df['intersection'] = np.nan
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    ## If-Statement to deal with Nans in col1
    if r['col1'] == r['col1']:
       df['intersection'][i] = len(set(r['col1']).intersection(set(lst)))
```

The problem is that this code is extremely time-consuming on my dataset of 200K rows and intersecting with a list of 200 elements. Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the if statement? It looks like always true to me?

Comment: to check for nans. x==x will return false if x is a nan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
lstset = set(lst)
df['intersection'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x).intersection(lstset)))
```

Another possibility is

```
df['intersection'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: len([1 for item in x if item in lst]))
```